# Redirect faulty URLs via htaccess (mod_rewrite)

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

For a while we had faulty urls on our website due to a technical error. Google had them indexed and now I try to redirect them to a page with a 410 HTTP status code.

For this example let's say the faulty urls are (all start with "abc" followed by a double slash):

```
https://www.example.com/abc//xxx/yyy
https://www.example.com/abc//nbe
https://www.example.com/abc//need/help
https://www.example.com/abc//my/htaccess-does-not-work
```

I tried to redirect those urls one by one in my htaccess, but those rules do not work:

```
RewriteRule ^abc//xxx/yyy$                          410_page_deleted.php [END,NC]
RewriteRule ^abc//nbe$                              410_page_deleted.php [END,NC]
RewriteRule ^abc//need/help$                        410_page_deleted.php [END,NC]
RewriteRule ^abc//my/htaccess-does-not-work$        410_page_deleted.php [END,NC]
```

I don't know why those rules are not working. I suspect it is due to the double slash because this works:

```
RewriteRule ^abc/my/htaccess-does-work$     410_page_deleted.php [END,NC]
```

I also tried this, but it didn't work either:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^abc/{2,}(.*)$
RewriteRule (.*) 410_page_deleted.php [END,NC]
```

Comment: Apache has likely "corrected" these double slashes internally already before this point. You'll need a solution then that works based on the originally requested URL - https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/8381

Comment: @CBroe Thank you very much for your answer. Sorry, I don't get it. These are the originally requested URLs. I don't know, what you mean. The link you posted also uses mod rewrite at the end.

Comment: REQUEST_URI is the path component of the URL, you need to match that including the leading slash - try `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/abc//`